# How to parse Integers from File in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have integers in a text file `n.txt` in the format, 2 columns of integers and the columns are separated by an empty space.

I want to read these integers and escape the space in between and input these two integers in 2 separate integers. The below code is used for parsing the `String` obtained. I wanted to know if there are any `String` methods instead with which I can split the `String` into to separate arrays and use empty space as a delimiter ?

```
String URL="C:\\User\\Nimit\\Desktop\\n.txt";
File f = new File(URL);
FileReader inputF = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputF);

int[] a= new int [1000];
int[] b= new int [1000];

String s =in.readLine();

while(s!=null)
{
    int i = 0;
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(s,b[i]); //this is line 19

    //*not important*// System.out.println(a[i]);
    s = in.readLine(); 
}

in.close();

System.out.println("the output of the file is " +f);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use the `Scanner`:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

int[] a = new int[1000];
int[] b = new int[1000];

int count = 0;
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    a[count] = s.nextInt();
    b[count] = s.nextInt();
    count++;
}

s.close();
```

Comment: It's going to go belly up if one odd line has only one integer ;)
Harder to verify the format like this.

Comment: Yepp, correct, and it will still work if there are other space characters like `\t`...

Comment: Got it. Finally! Was trying to debug it from 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

User `split()` method of `String` class. `String arr[]="A B C".split(" ");`

P.S: Since you said here's a newbie tip. Use Google first, most of the time you will find answers much quicker than when you were posting a question here! And read the Java-doc because you can find most of the answers there. Just skim through that before Googling and then come here or any other forum to ask a question.

Comment: Yes. But I want to split the string, and put into to two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should first read the documentation whenever you have a question like this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

What it seems you're looking for is String.Split()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
s = in.readLine(); 
while(s!=null && i<1000) // your arrays can only hold 1000 ints
{
   String pair[] = s.split(" ");
   a[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[0]);
   b[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
   i++; // don't forget to increment
   s = in.readLine(); 
}
```

Something like this.